# Modifying HEAD elements with Ember.js -- canonical url link

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-data, canonical-link

I have a URL structure that provides keywords but ignores them.

EG: `/album/could-be-anything/12`

Which will look up an album by the id 12.

But since the keywords could be modified, in order to protect myself from "duplicate content" I know that I need to implement `link rel="canonical"` into the HEAD.  The canonical url will be coming back from my model's api.

```
<head>
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/album/album-name/12/">
</head>
<body>
    ... applicationController ...
</body>
```

I am not sure how or where exactly the best way to accomplish this is in Ember.js.  Should I use jQuery to set the href attribute in a certain callback?  If so, what would be the best callback to use?  Or could I create a controller for the head with a `bindAttr` on the href?

Also, this might happen in a route nested deeply... how can I be sure the hook will fire at the right time and not be overridden by some other (shallower) hook?

Comment: This addon can help.  The README has an example with `canonical` . https://github.com/ronco/ember-cli-meta-tags